# Gerrit: limit number of open changes for a project?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

is it possible to configure a hard limit on the number of open changes for a given project in Gerrit?

When too many changes accumulate, rebasing them becomes an issue, especially when every rebase triggers a Jenkins job which takes some time to complete. 
Hence I am looking for a way to force a limit on the open changes, so that Gerrit rejects new changes when too many are still open.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). You can then use gerrit's [ssh api](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html) or directly talk to gerrit's database to query outstanding gerrits.

Alternatively, consider using polling in jenkins instead of triggering a build on every change.